# Python dictionary creation syntax

Tags: python, syntax, dictionary

I'm wondering if there's any way to populate a dictionary such that you have multiple keys mapping to the same value that's less verbose than say:

```
d = {1:'yes', 2:'yes', 3:'yes', 4:'no'}
```

I'm thinking something along the lines of:

```
d = {*(1,2,3):'yes', 4:'no'}
```

which is obviously a syntax error.

Is there a reasonably simple method of doing this without TOO much obfuscation? (I'm not playing code golf, but I also don't need to write essentially the same thing over and over. However, any code-golf related answers would be appreciated as well since code-golf is awesome =]).

**Edit**:

I probably picked a bad example. This is what I'm trying to do:

```
d = {*('READY', 95): 'GPLR2_95', 'CHARGING': 'GPLR3_99', 'PROTECTION': 'GPLR3_100', 'CONNECTED': 'GPLR3_101', 'ERROR':'GPLR3_102'}
```

What I would expect this to expand to is:

```
d = {'READY':'GPLR2_95', 95: 'GPLR2_95', ...}
```

**Edit->Edit**:

I know this is stupid and totally unnecessary, but my goal is to make this declaration on a single line. This obviously shouldn't limit any responses and writing code just because it fits on 1 line is stupid. But I'm writing a module level constant dict that would be nice if it was a single liner.

Comment: Obviously, `d = collections.defaultdict(lambda : 'yes')` is not what you are looking for?

Comment: Reversing your keys would work as well... 'yes': (1,2,3)

Comment: @Nix: Yes it's just my example. I'll update it to be slightly more in line with my application.

Comment: No need, just wanted to make sure a different way of thinking about it didn't remove your need to do it..

Comment: It's unclear (to me at least) what this *('READY', 95): 'GPLR2_95' item means?  Is there 95 of these?  ...could you give us the first few maybe?

Comment: Sorry, I guess another poor example. The * in python expands the tuple. So I'll update.

Comment: Oh, for crying out loud.  Write a little function that takes the tuple and vector as arguments.  Write an iterator.  Write it, for Gods' sakes, on more than one line.  Someone else may have to read this someday.

Comment: You can also, simply use multi key dict https://pypi.org/project/multi_key_dict/#:~:text=Multi-key%20dict%20provides%20also,using%20either%3A%20names%20or%20indexes.

Answer (score 87, accepted):

You could turn it around:

```
>>> d1 = {"yes": [1,2,3], "no": [4]}
```

and then "invert" that dictionary:

```
>>> d2 = {value:key for key in d1 for value in d1[key]}
>>> d2
{1: 'yes', 2: 'yes', 3: 'yes', 4: 'no'}
```

Comment: Augh.  You're doing all that to avoid having to repeat "yes" a few times?  Okay, it's cute in the code-golf sense, but then code golf is pernicious too.

Comment: I agree this isn't pretty. Clever, maybe, but not really pretty. My first solution was a little helper function (with nested, readable 'for' loops). But he wanted a one-liner so I gave him one. Not that I'd do this in my own code - nested dict comprehensions are often hard to read.

Comment: My worry about readability wasn't so much about the nested dict comprehension, but more about the confusion caused by inverting and transforming a dictionary that was just defined.  If I were reading the code I might miss the inversion, or notice it and wonder what purpose it served.

Answer (score 9):

How about:

```
501 $ python
Python 2.7.1+ (r271:86832, Apr 11 2011, 18:13:53) 
[GCC 4.5.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> a = {"q":1}
>>> print a
{'q': 1}
>>> a["q"]
1
>>> a["r"] = a["s"] = a["t"] = 2
>>> a
{'q': 1, 's': 2, 'r': 2, 't': 2}
>>>
```

Answer (score 4):

Code golf?

```
yesindices = [1,2,3,22,34,33]
noindices = [4,8,9]
dict (zip(yesindices, ['yes' for i in yesindices]) + zip(noindices, ['no' for i in noindices]))
```

yields

```
{1: 'yes', 2: 'yes', 3: 'yes', 4: 'no', 33: 'yes', 8: 'no', 9: 'no', 34: 'yes', 22: 'yes'}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
d = {'READY': 'GPLR2_95',
    95: 'GPLR2_95',
    'CHARGING': 'GPLR3_99',
    'PROTECTION': 'GPLR3_100',
    'CONNECTED': 'GPLR3_101',
    'ERROR':'GPLR3_102'}
```

What's wrong with breaking this into multiple lines (as above)?  Is the point saving typing or saving vertical space?  Something else?

BTW, it feels really strange to have keys that are a mix of numbers and strings.

**note:** I wrote this as an answer instead of a comment because I wanted to show formatted code on multiple lines.

Comment: It's not the multiple LINES that I was trying to avoid. I guess that's an outdated term? Or I've always been using it incorrectly? I actually meant multiple statements.

Comment: @Falmarri  In that case what's wrong with doing it on multiple lines like I show?  I'm not being critical, I'm just trying to understand your requirements.  I've enjoyed some code-golf type answers.

Comment: Nothing is inherently wrong with it. I just have 4-5 keys that point to the same value, and there's about 8 or 9 values. So that's 9*5 dictionary definitions. I'm just looking for something a little more compact.

Answer (score 2):

How about this?

```py
d = {
    **{k:'yes' for k in [1,2,3]},
    **{k:'no' for k in [4]}
}
```

It's less verbose than the accepted answer and more intuitive than inverting a dictionary.

Comment: I have been looking for this for such a long time, I knew we could do it, just wasn't sure how. Do you know the name of this feature?

Comment: @JuanPablo Not sure which feature you mean. `**` is the unpacking operator for dictionaries.

Answer (score 1):

```
dict((x, {4: 'no'}.get(x, 'yes')) for x in range(1, 5))
```

Or in 3.x:

```
{x: {4: 'no'}.get(x, 'yes') for x in range(1, 5)}
```

Comment: As I've updated, the keys are both strings and ints that need to be mapped to strings. So it was a poor example, as range() isn't all that applicable.

Comment: So what. Just use a proper sequence instead of calling `range()`.

Answer (score 1):

For your case

```
dict([(_, 'yes') for _ in range(1,4)], **{4:'no'})
```

And if you need multiple keys for `'yes'` and `'no'`

```
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> dict(chain([(_, 'yes') for _ in range(1,4)], [(_, 'no') for _ in range(4, 10)]))
{1: 'yes', 2: 'yes', 3: 'yes', 4: 'no', 5: 'no', 6: 'no', 7: 'no', 8: 'no', 9: 'no'}
```

Not so great, but works.

Answer (score 1):

Try to iterate through the `dict` items.

- For python 2.x

  {key: value for key, value in your_dict.iteritems()}
- For python 3.x

  {key: value for key, value in your_dict.items()}