# Less code on multi key dictionary initialization

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

I have such code (Python 2.7+):

```
target = "some_string_key1_key3_key5_key6"

some_dict = {
    'key1': 'value1',
    'key2': 'value1',
    'key3': 'value2',
    'key4': 'value2',
    'key5': 'value3',
    'kyy6': 'value4',
}

for k, v in some_dict.iteritems():
    target = target.replace(k, v)
```

As you can see, there are different keys using the same value (key1 and key2 / key3 and key4). All keys and values are strings in my case.

Is there any possibility to have less code on dictionary initialization and still get

```
for k, v in some_dict.iteritems()
```

behavior unchanged with only standart python 2.7 modules?

I tried [multi_key_dict](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/multi_key_dict), but for me it is less convinient, because of slightly different syntax.

All I want to achieve is something like that:

```
new_cool_dict = {
    ['key1', 'key2', ]: 'value1',
    ['key3', 'key4', ]: 'value2',
    'key5': 'value3',
    'key6': 'value6',
}

for k, v in new_cool_dict.iteritems():
    target = target.replace(k, v)
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python dictionary creation syntax](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6191672/python-dictionary-creation-syntax)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend making the keys as tuples and change your `for` loop a little, like this

```
target = "some_string_key1_key3_key5_key6"

some_dict = {
    ('key1', 'key2'): 'value1',
    ('key3', 'key4'): 'value2',
    ('key5',): 'value3',
    ('key6',): 'value6',
}

for k, v in some_dict.iteritems():
    target = reduce(lambda x, y: x.replace(y, v), k, target)

print target
```

**Output**

```
some_string_value1_value2_value3_value6
```

Comment: Wow, it is almost that I wanted :) Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

I'd find this to be *less* useful and readable, but you can use multiple assignments on one line:

```
some_dict = {
    'key5': 'value3',
    'kyy6': 'value4',
}
some_dict['key1'] = some_dict['key2'] = 'value1'
some_dict['key3'] = some_dict['key4'] = 'value2'
```

The alternative would be to build a factory function that expands tuple keys:

```
def expand_tuple_keys(d):
    result = {}
    for key, value in d.iteritems():
        if not hasattr(key, '__iter__'):
            key = (key,)
        result.update((k, value) for k in key)
    return result
```

then use:

```
new_cool_dict = expand_tuple_keys({
    ('key1', 'key2'): 'value1',
    ('key3', 'key4'): 'value2',
    'key5': 'value3',
    'key6': 'value6',
})
```

Demo:

```
>>> def expand_tuple_keys(d):
...     result = {}
...     for key, value in d.iteritems():
...         if not hasattr(key, '__iter__'):
...             key = (key,)
...         result.update((k, value) for k in key)
...     return result
... 
>>> expand_tuple_keys({
...     ('key1', 'key2'): 'value1',
...     ('key3', 'key4'): 'value2',
...     'key5': 'value3',
...     'key6': 'value6',
... })
{'key3': 'value2', 'key2': 'value1', 'key1': 'value1', 'key6': 'value6', 'key5': 'value3', 'key4': 'value2'}
```

Comment: This is at least arguably more maintainable/DRY, since you don't repeat string literals.

Comment: This is bad if you want keys to be both single values and also `tuple`s. For example, if I really wanted `{'a':1, ('b', 'c'):2}` with the `tuple` `('b', 'c')` as one of the keys, but then wanted to add a repeated value for two distinct keys, `'d'` and `'e'`. It might be better to make it only work as "`expand_list_keys`" since `list` is not hashable and therefore can't be mistaken as a possible key on its own.

Comment: @EMS: You cannot use `list` objects as keys. You can always use a `(('a', 'b'),)` single item tuple with a tuple as the only value.

Comment: @EMS: Note that I now pass in a dictionary; you'd have to switch to a list of tuples instead then, which gets verbose and tedious fast.

Comment: No, I am saying you should not use the dict itself within `expand_tuple_keys`. I apologize if this is not clear -- I think you are not understanding my suggestion. I'm saying, don't start with anything that ever has tuples as keys and that then get modified. Instead, pass `list`s (and don't use the `{}` notation in that case) so there can be no confusion with the native way that `dict` handles `tuple` keys.

Comment: @EMS: Yes, that was clear. I am saying the argument to that function then gets to be overly verbose and cumbersome. Just to support tuple keys. The use-case isn't special enough to overhaul the whole concept, I'd say. Document the nested tuple syntax and be done with it, much simpler, more readable, and no hobbling the syntax because of a most-likely-obscure edge case.

Comment: For example: `expand_list_keys([(['key1', 'key2'], 'value1'), ('key5', 'value3')])` which are then handled in the function and a `dict` is created and returned. Hardly more verbose than usual, and much less chance of forgetting that you didn't want some particular `tuple` expanded but did want others expanded.

Comment: @EMS: Yes, I understood what you meant, that's why I said *you'd have to switch to a list of tuples instead, which gets verbose and tedious fast*.

Comment: Thank you for such great example!

It's my favorite answer after @thefourtheye. I'll definitely will try to use it.

Answer (score 4):

You could also define your dictionary the other way around for convenience:

```
my_dict = {
    'value1': ['key1', 'key2'],
    'value2': ['key3', 'key4'],
    'value3': ['key5']
}
```

And then convert it into a more usable representation:

```
>>> dict((k, v) for (v, l) in my_dict.iteritems() for k in l)
{'key1': 'value1',
 'key2': 'value1',
 'key3': 'value2',
 'key4': 'value2',
 'key5': 'value3'}
```

Answer (score 1):

Inverse keys and values ;-)

```
dict = { 
   'value1': ['key1', 'key2'],
   'value2': ['key3', 'key3'],
   'value3': ['key5'],
   'value4': ['key6']

}



for v, ks in dict.iteritems:
   for k in ks:
       target = target.replace.(k, v)
```

Bob's your uncle (althout I would probably rename k to v and vice versa