# Converting a list of tuple of 2+ elements to a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a list of tuples which have more that 2 elements where the first element of each tuple is a number which is unique across all the tuples. How can I convert that list of tuples into a dictionary where a key is the 1st element of each tuple?

I know I can use `dict(mylist)` but it works only for 2-element tuples.

Comment: You should be able to use a dictionary comprehension. What have you tried?

Comment: you parse each tuple, setting the first element as a key, and the rest to the value of said key

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python dictionary creation syntax](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6191672/python-dictionary-creation-syntax)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use CoryKramer's answer if you are using Python 2, avoid the explicit indexing in favor of [Extended Iterable Unpacking](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3132/) if you are using Python 3.

```
>>> lst = [(1, 'a', 'b'), (2, 'c', 'd')]
>>> {key:tuple(rest) for key, *rest in lst}
{1: ('a', 'b'), 2: ('c', 'd')}
```

Comment: Wow! `for key,*rest in lst` that's so `lisp`

Comment: @quamrana I don't know any lisp. but the extended unpacking always reminds me of Haskell. (Of course, Haskell has far more powerful pattern matching assingments.)

Comment: how can I create an array instead of tuple as a value?

Comment: @Otoma `{key:rest for key, *rest in lst}` if by "array" you mean list.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `dict` comprehension

```
>>> l = [(1, 'a', 'b'),
         (2, 'c', 'd')]
>>> {i[0]: i[1:] for i in l}
{1: ('a', 'b'),
 2: ('c', 'd')}
```